# AngularJS e Image Picker - Não consigo capturar conteúdo do selecionador

Tags: angularjs, select, image, img

estou com a seguinte dúvida:

Se eu clicar no selecionador (na caixa), eu consigo capturar o conteúdo do ng-model "primeiroJogo" e manipula-lo no javascript conforme a necessidade:

```
<p>Escolha o jogo</p> 
<select class="image-picker show-html" ng-model="primeiroJogo">
    <option
      data-img-src='../public/images/logosmite.jpg'
      value="Smite"
      class="image-picker"
    ></option>
    <option
      data-img-src='../public/images/logohmm.jpg'
      value="Heavy Metal Machines"
      class="image-picker"
    ></option>
</select>
```

Mas o que eu preciso é que seja possível capturar o conteúdo desse ng-model caso o usuário clique diretamente na imagem. Alguém saberia me informar como posso fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual angular vc esta uisando?

Comment: Olá Eduardo, boa noite. AngularJS v1.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe alguma necessidade de usar o `select`?

Você consegue o resultado que deseja usando o [input:radio](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)

Ficaria algo assim:

```
<p>Escolha o jogo</p>
<div class="image-picker show-html">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="primeiroJogo" value="Smite">
    <img src="../public/images/logosmite.jpg" alt="">
  </label><br />
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="primeiroJogo" value="Heavy Metal Machines">
    <img src="../public/images/logohmm.jpg" alt="">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Vou testar assim que estiver no meu computador e te passo o feedback. Desde já agradeço. Rep +